# how to modify text2 (subtitle) , if i want to make different text every cardview?? (with arraylist )

Tags: android, android-studio, arraylist, android-recyclerview, cardview

i want to set text2 into different text for each cardview with arraylist,

i dont know how to use arraylist into my code, in MainActivity.java i have use 'for' to index number of cardview but i dont know how to use it on text2

hope everyone help me on this..

thx..

this is my MainActivity.java

```
package rachman.a.haditsarbain;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private static String LOG_TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(getDataSet());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Code to Add an item with default animation
        //((MyRecyclerViewAdapter) mAdapter).addItem(obj, index);

        // Code to remove an item with default animation
        //((MyRecyclerViewAdapter) mAdapter).deleteItem(index);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ((MyRecyclerViewAdapter) mAdapter).setOnItemClickListener(new MyRecyclerViewAdapter
                .MyClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, " Clicked on Item " + position);
            }
        });
    }

    private ArrayList<DataObject> getDataSet() {
        ArrayList results = new ArrayList<DataObject>();
        for (int index=0; index <43; index++) {
            DataObject obj = new DataObject("Title " + (index+1),
                    "Sub Title ");

            results.add(index, obj);
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

this is MyRecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
package rachman.a.haditsarbain;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView
        .Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter
        .DataObjectHolder> {
    private static String LOG_TAG = "MyRecyclerViewAdapter";
    private ArrayList<DataObject> mDataset;
    private static MyClickListener myClickListener;

    public static class DataObjectHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements View
            .OnClickListener {
        TextView label;
        TextView dateTime;

        public DataObjectHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            label = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            dateTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Adding Listener");
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
        }
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(MyClickListener myClickListener) {
        this.myClickListener = myClickListener;
    }

    public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<DataObject> myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public DataObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_view_row, parent, false);

        DataObjectHolder dataObjectHolder = new DataObjectHolder(view);
        return dataObjectHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataObjectHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.label.setText(mDataset.get(position).getmText1());
        holder.dateTime.setText(mDataset.get(position).getmText2());
    }

    public void addItem(DataObject dataObj, int index) {
        mDataset.add(index, dataObj);
        notifyItemInserted(index);
    }

    public void deleteItem(int index) {
        mDataset.remove(index);
        notifyItemRemoved(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

    public interface MyClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(int position, View v);
    }
}
```

and this is my DataObject.java

```
package rachman.a.haditsarbain;

public class DataObject {
    private String mText1;
    private String mText2;

    DataObject (String text1, String text2){
        mText1 = text1;
        mText2 = text2;
    }

    public String getmText1() {
        return mText1;
    }

    public void setmText1(String mText1) {
        this.mText1 = mText1;
    }

    public String getmText2() {
        return mText2;
    }

    public void setmText2(String mText2) {
        this.mText2 = mText2;
    }
}
```

Comment: you have already set text2 on your cardview. what  going wrong on your code ?

Comment: text2 is always 'subtitle', i want to change it, so every cardview has different text

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
DataObject obj = new DataObject("Title " + (index+1), "Sub Title ");
```

You are creating `DataObject` with a dynamic text ( "Title 1, Title 2, Title 3 etc). However, your Second Parameter is always "Sub Title".

I'm not sure which text do you want to set... But just change that second parameter and you will have the text that you want.. Something like like:

```
DataObject obj = new DataObject("Title " + (index+1), "Sub Title " + (index+1));
```

Comment: text2 is always 'subtitle', i want to change it, so every cardview has different text

Answer (score 0):

Check below code snippet :

```
 private ArrayList<DataObject> getDataSet() {
    ArrayList<String> subtitle=new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<31;i++){
        subtitle.add(i+1+"/01/2018");
    }
    ArrayList results = new ArrayList<DataObject>();
    for (int index=0; index <31; index++) {
        DataObject obj = new DataObject("Title " + (index+1),
                subtitle.get(index));

        results.add(index, obj);
    }
    return results;
}
```

I wrote this to give you an idea on how you can create dynamic subtitle. Let me know if it helps.